# What is the name and specs for the RPi CM 4's GPIO connectors?

Tags: gpio, hardware, wiring, compute-module

I want to use a compute module for a personal project; but I don't know the name of the connector that is used for the GPIO/SPI etc.  It is the one pictured here

[image: here]

In the spec sheets, I see the pin out definitions, but not the name or specification of the two connectors.

Basically; i want SPI, GPIO and USB broken out; and need to know what to buy for the daughter boards and what cable/connectors to get.

(Prototyping will be done with  the dev kit board)

Answer (score 1):

I understand they are '100pin Hirose DF40JC high-density connectors' and they they don't just carry the GPIO connections they carry all of the Raspberry pi's IO HDMI, USB,  Networking etc.